# Python to format and create a nested JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am using pandas "to_json" option to generate some JSON files after filtering DF. The output of these comes as below:

```
[{"time":1677287760000,"x":0.001,"y":0.001,"z":0.0},{"time":1677632400000,"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},{"time":1677636000000,"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},{"time":1677639600000,"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0}]
```

and

```
[{"dt":20,"count":6},{"dt":23,"count":9},{"dt":11,"count":7},{"dt":2,"count":16},{"dt":17,"count":1},{"dt":20,"count":6}]
```

I am looking for options to create a JSON file in python which will hold both as below:

```
{
    "StatusTimes": [
        {
            "time": 1677287760000,
            "x": 0.001,
            "y": 0.001,
            "z": 0
        },
        {
            "time": 1677632400000,
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "z": 0
        },
        {
            "time": 1677636000000,
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "z": 0
        },
        {
            "time": 1677639600000,
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "z": 0
        }
    ],
    "DtCount": [
        {
            "dt": 20,
            "count": 6
        },
        {
            "dt": 23,
            "count": 9
        },
        {
            "dt": 11,
            "count": 7
        },
        {
            "dt": 2,
            "count": 16
        },
        {
            "dt": 17,
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "dt": 20,
            "count": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried json dumps and then update to get errors. I was thinking to create a JSON object and then update the value as needed. i.e to start with

```
{
    "StatusTimes": [],
    "DtCount": []
}
```

Adding a name to the specific inner JSON object also didn't work. Appreciate the help here

Comment: Remember that JSON conversion is _always_ the very last step. Once you've done that, you now have a completely "useless"string (that you can then make useful again somewhere else by parsing it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating a json file you can create a dictionary with the keys "StatusTimes". Then you can use json.dumps() to convert the dictionary into a JSON formatted string. This is example:

```
import json

# Your data
status_times = [{"time":1677287760000,"x":0.001,"y":0.001,"z":0.0},{"time":1677632400000,"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},{"time":1677636000000,"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},{"time":1677639600000,"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0}]
dt_count = [{"dt":20,"count":6},{"dt":23,"count":9},{"dt":11,"count":7},{"dt":2,"count":16},{"dt":17,"count":1},{"dt":20,"count":6}]

# Create a dictionary
data = {
    "StatusTimes": status_times,
    "DtCount": dt_count
}

# Convert the dictionary to a JSON string
json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)

# Write the JSON string to a file
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json_data)
```

This will create a JSON file named output.json in your current directory with the desired structure.

Comment: Thank for checking this. It is doing the job to get it added however, it is having backslashs added to the data as in the sample below with just one data. ` { "StatusTimes": "[{\"time\":1677286800000,\"x\":0.0,\"y\":0.0,\"z\":0.0},{\"time\":1677287760000,\"x\":0.001,\"y\":0.001,\"z\":0.0}]" } `

Comment: Bit of playing with formatting fixed the double encoding issue

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to use the `to_dict` function instead: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict

Example:

```
json_variable = {
    "StatusTimes": df1.to_dict('records'),
    "DtCount": df2.to_dict('records'),
}
with open('output.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(json_variable, fp)
```

If you want the beautified json:

```
json_variable = {
    "StatusTimes": df1.to_dict('records'),
    "DtCount": df2.to_dict('records'),
}
json_data = json.dumps(json_variable, indent=4)
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json_data)
```

Comment: Thank you for checking this. to_dict is affecting the "time" which is needed in epoch. to_json was helping to keep it as epoch itself